# How get only characters between `(` and `)` using regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I am having a scenario like this:

`A= add(1a,2b,3c,4d)` now i want only the values inside the brackets .How can i do that ?Can anyone help me.

I tried using this:

`replaceAll("\\d","");` It removed all the integers, but I want to get the char inside the bracket with commas.

For example: `a,b,c,d`

Comment: can there be parentheses in the actual values of a, b, c, d? in that case, regex would not be the way to go.

Comment: add(a,b,c,d)  now i want to remove the characters outside and to get the char inside the brackets with commas.The output i want is a,b,c,d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you require is: `"\\((.*)\\)"`.

The code below demonstrates how to use this pattern to find all the occurrences of items enclosed in brackets in an input string:

```
String example = "A= add(a,b,c,d)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*)\\)");    
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(example);

while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Prints:

```
a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 3):

```
([0-9()]|.*(?=\())
```

`[0-9()]` This will match the digits and brackets

`.*(?=\()` This will match anything before the opening bracket

The `|` in the middle acts like an `OR` e.g. match `(THIS | THIS)`

In your case with a replace this `A= add(1a,2b,3c,4d)` will become `a,b,c,d`

Test here and choose the replace tab at the top http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: +1, but it took me a while to figure out what you were doing.  You can make your intention a little more obvious by tweaking it to `([0-9()]+|^.*(?=\())`.  The addition of the `+` and `^` doesn't change what gets matched, and as an added bonus it makes the regex more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Regex:

`\\((.*?)\\)`

If you want to extract the chars without the `,`, you can use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Your solution doesn't work because you are doing something irrelevant. You are replacing all digits with `""`, meaning that you're removing them.

Another solution:

```
String myStr = str.split("\\(|\\)")[1];
```

---

If your string is `A= add(1a,2b,3c,4d)`, after the regex, you'll get `1a,2b,3c,4d`. If you don't want the `int`s, use `replaceAll`.

Comment: yes i am replacing integers with null and i want the characters inside  the bracket with commas

Comment: I am getting the answer like add a,b,c,d

Comment: I want only the a,b,c,d not add

Comment: @user2841300 That's what you wanted no? To get `a,b,c,d`

Answer (score 1):

`\(([^\)]*)\)` will give back in the first group `"a,b,c,d"`.